# How to extract a number

Tags: python, string, dictionary, text-extraction

From a query i get a return that i converted into a dict as i want to extract the 'last_price': '**1704.50**'. I tried it with find, count ... but it seems that i'm running into a wall.

here is the string  & it looks like that the bracket makes it harder to extract:

`dict_items([('ret_code', 0), ('ret_msg', 'OK'), ('ext_code', ''), ('ext_info', ''), ('result', **[**{'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'bid_price': '1701.8', 'ask_price': '1702', **'last_price': '1704.50'**, 'last_tick_direction': 'PlusTick', 'prev_price_24h': '1647.55', 'price_24h_pcnt': '0.034566', 'high_price_24h': '1710.55', 'low_price_24h': '1620.40', 'prev_price_1h': '1679.40', 'price_1h_pcnt': '0.014945', 'mark_price': '1702.51', 'index_price': '1702.38', 'open_interest': 150155.81, 'open_value': '0.00', 'total_turnover': '54418340521.33', 'turnover_24h': '63239638.53', 'total_volume': 58525803.73, 'volume_24h': 37976.79, 'funding_rate': '0.0001', 'predicted_funding_rate': '0.0001', 'next_funding_time': '2022-08-25T08:00:00Z', 'countdown_hour': 1, 'delivery_fee_rate': '', 'predicted_delivery_price': '', 'delivery_time': ''}**]**), ('time_now', '1661411154.330653')])`

Comment: `d['result'][0]['last_price']`?

Answer (score 0):

Hope I'm uderstanding it right but this works for me:

`d=dict([('ret_code', 0), ('ret_msg', 'OK'), ('ext_code', ''), ('ext_info', ''), ('result', [{'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'bid_price': '1701.8', 'ask_price': '1702', 'last_price': '1704.50', 'last_tick_direction': 'PlusTick', 'prev_price_24h': '1647.55', 'price_24h_pcnt': '0.034566', 'high_price_24h': '1710.55', 'low_price_24h': '1620.40', 'prev_price_1h': '1679.40', 'price_1h_pcnt': '0.014945', 'mark_price': '1702.51', 'index_price': '1702.38', 'open_interest': 150155.81, 'open_value': '0.00', 'total_turnover': '54418340521.33', 'turnover_24h': '63239638.53', 'total_volume': 58525803.73, 'volume_24h': 37976.79, 'funding_rate': '0.0001', 'predicted_funding_rate': '0.0001', 'next_funding_time': '2022-08-25T08:00:00Z', 'countdown_hour': 1, 'delivery_fee_rate': '', 'predicted_delivery_price': '', 'delivery_time': ''}]), ('time_now', '1661411154.330653')])`

`d['result'][0]['last_price']`

gives the number. Notice the [0] due to the "[ ]" you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with texts, regex might be more appropriate:

```
import re

text = """dict_items([('ret_code', 0), ('ret_msg', 'OK'), ('ext_code', ''), ('ext_info', ''), ('result', [{'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'bid_price': '1701.8', 'ask_price': '1702', 'last_price': '1704.50', 'last_tick_direction': 'PlusTick', 'prev_price_24h': '1647.55', 'price_24h_pcnt': '0.034566', 'high_price_24h': '1710.55', 'low_price_24h': '1620.40', 'prev_price_1h': '1679.40', 'price_1h_pcnt': '0.014945', 'mark_price': '1702.51', 'index_price': '1702.38', 'open_interest': 150155.81, 'open_value': '0.00', 'total_turnover': '54418340521.33', 'turnover_24h': '63239638.53', 'total_volume': 58525803.73, 'volume_24h': 37976.79, 'funding_rate': '0.0001', 'predicted_funding_rate': '0.0001', 'next_funding_time': '2022-08-25T08:00:00Z', 'countdown_hour': 1, 'delivery_fee_rate': '', 'predicted_delivery_price': '', 'delivery_time': ''}]), ('time_now', '1661411154.330653')])"""
last_price_pattern = r"'last_price'\s*:\s*'(\d*\.\d*)'"

last_price = float(re.findall(last_price_pattern, text)[0])
print(last_price)
```

If you're dealing with a list, then simple indexing will suffice:

```
raw_data = [('ret_code', 0), ('ret_msg', 'OK'), ('ext_code', ''), ('ext_info', ''), ('result', [{'symbol': 'ETHUSDT', 'bid_price': '1701.8', 'ask_price': '1702', 'last_price': '1704.50', 'last_tick_direction': 'PlusTick', 'prev_price_24h': '1647.55', 'price_24h_pcnt': '0.034566', 'high_price_24h': '1710.55', 'low_price_24h': '1620.40', 'prev_price_1h': '1679.40', 'price_1h_pcnt': '0.014945', 'mark_price': '1702.51', 'index_price': '1702.38', 'open_interest': 150155.81, 'open_value': '0.00', 'total_turnover': '54418340521.33', 'turnover_24h': '63239638.53', 'total_volume': 58525803.73, 'volume_24h': 37976.79, 'funding_rate': '0.0001', 'predicted_funding_rate': '0.0001', 'next_funding_time': '2022-08-25T08:00:00Z', 'countdown_hour': 1, 'delivery_fee_rate': '', 'predicted_delivery_price': '', 'delivery_time': ''}]), ('time_now', '1661411154.330653')]
last_price = float(raw_data[4][1][0]['last_price'])
print(last_price)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
# Extract the result list from the dictionary
result_list = my_dict['result']

# Get the first (and only) item from the result list
result_item = result_list[0]

# Extract the value of the 'last_price' key from the result item
last_price = result_item['last_price']

print(last_price)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including a detailed explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.